# Multi line input different output in python

Tags: python, input, printing, output

I am a new self-paced student trying to learn python (3.x.x). I'm trying to use 
ONE variable to take in different input(s)(names) and output them in print statements.

```
reference = input('Who is your first reference: ') 
reference = input('Who is your second reference: ')

print ('Your first reference is: ' + reference)
print ('Your second reference is: ' + reference)
```

Desired output

```
Your first reference is: Thabo Mbeki
Your second reference is: Allan Turig
```

Answer (score 1):

To store two elements within the same variable, you would use a [list](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Lists).

Like such :

```
reference = []

reference.append(input('Who is your first reference: ')) 
reference.append(input('Who is your second reference: '))

print ('Your first reference is: ' + reference[0])# Lists start at 0. the 1st element
print ('Your second reference is: ' + reference[1])# 2nd element
```

Lists are stored as `['1st input', '2nd input']` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you are ovewriting the `reference` input variable on the second read.

You can try something like:

```
reference1, reference2 = input('Who is your first and second reference?').split()
print(f'Your first reference is {reference1} \n Your second reference is {reference2}')
```

Read about [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) in Python (3.6+) which is what I did to pass variables into the string without concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store 2 values in a single variable.
You have 2 options.
You can have 2 separate variables

```
reference1 = input('Who is your first reference: ') 
reference2 = input('Who is your second reference: ')

print ('Your first reference is: ' + reference1)
print ('Your second reference is: ' + reference2)
```

Or you can use a list.

```
references = []

reference = input('Who is your first reference: ')
references.append(reference)

reference = input('Who is your first reference: ')
references.append(reference)

print ('Your first reference is: ' + references[0])
print ('Your second reference is: ' + reference[1])
```

Here's an example of a list variable with a for loop(used to make code shorter)

```
references = []

for i in range(2):
    reference = input('Who is your reference: ')
    references.append(reference)

for i in range(len(references)):
    print('Your reference is: ' + reference[i])
```

If you don't care about numbers (first and second) I recommend you use this one.
Also I recommend you remember using lists since it is the most "programmer" way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses, I guess I thought could use the one variable to take in the different inputs, because I may have up to six 'reference' requests in the script. So list it is then.

Comment: Yes in that case use a list. If you want those numbers like (first and second)  just say. I can reply with some code. :D

Comment: Also if you don't know how long the list will exactly be. You can ask the user to input list size. Then in the for loop, instead of number 2 in this case, you write that variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user for the list lenth and store it in to a variable.
Then you can use that variable as the for loop length.

```
number_of_references = int(input('How many references do you have: '))
references = []

for i in range(number_of_references):
    reference = input('What is your reference?: ')
    references.append(reference)

for i in range(len(references)):
    print('Your reference is' + references[i])
```

This is it. Do you need anything else?